# I got error in google direction

Tags: iphone

```
UIWebView *fullWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,45,320,435)];

fullWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

fullWebView.delegate =self;

[fullWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL                            URLWithString: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=dsaddr=37.331689,-122.030731daddr=37.324188,-122.036144]];

[self addSubview:fullWebView];

[fullWebView release], fullWebView = nil;
```

this is my code and once i load this code i will get google direction page in my webview;
but once i click walking direction, my app got crashed.

and i have got this errors.

```
(

    3816,0xb0081000) malloc: *** error for object 0x18c5000: pointer being freed was not allocated
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    (gdb) continue
    [Switching to process 3816]
    Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
    [Switching to process 3816]
```

i set breakpoint in malloc_error_break but i can't trace anything about app crash.

Basically i need driving direction, walking direction and bus direction for may app, so i tried this link in my web view.

can any one help me to clear this error or get google map directions in web view

Answer (score 0):

Crash shows you are trying to access an object which is freed.if you can,t find with malloc_error_break then use NSZombie in your project see this [link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

it gives you the object then you need to manually find that object.